# How do the Kitronik Robotics Boards' motor outputs work only for motors specifically?

Tags: robotics, bbc-microbit, motordriver

I was under the belief that I can connect anything to the motor outputs on the board and it will function as a simple dc power supply. However, connecting one of the outputs to an LED does not light the LED . The code is just a simple :

```
Kitronik_Robotics_Board.motorOn(Kitronik_Ro 
botics_Board.Motors.Motor2, 
  
Kitronik_Robotics_Board.MotorDirection.Forward, ledVoltageInSpeed)
```

Why do they work only on motors?

I have tested with multiple voltage inputs into the board. The lights also work when connected directly to an external power supply.

Comment: Controlling the speed of DC motors is done by controlling the input voltage to the motors and the most common method of doing that is by using a PWM signal. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-width_modulation

Comment: This is mainly an electronics question not a programming one, I think? If you're using [this board](https://kitronik.co.uk/products/5693-compact-robotics-board-for-bbc-micro-bit), it uses an [H-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-bridge) to drive each motor, and it looks as if it can drive servos and stepper motors as well as DC motors, so you need to configure it for a DC motor and connect your LED the right way round (and with a series resistor!).